# Must manually load PHP ActiveRecord models

Tags: nginx, php, phpactiverecord

I'm drawing a blank.  I have code working locally (which is MAMP).  When moving to a nginx ubuntu box (running php-fpm), for some reason, phpactiverecord is acting up.

I finally traced it down to this - All of my model classes, I have to load manually. If I add a require_once() underneath my code, then it works fine.  If I don't, then I get errors like:

PHP Fatal Error: Class not found ... on the models I've created..

Does anyone have ANY idea what direction I could troubleshoot this in? I checked permissions to the models folder (which is not in the public root), echo'd out the path that is sent over to cfg->set_model_directory is correct, etc..

This sound like a nginx or php thing?  I'm guessing nginx since this works on my MAMP?

Doesn't work:

```
ActiveRecord\Config::initialize(
    function ($cfg) {
        $cfg->set_model_directory(BASE_PATH . '/models');
        $cfg->set_connections(
            array(
                'development' => 'mysql://blah:removed@localhost/com_dbname'
            )
        );
    }
);
```

Works:

```
ActiveRecord\Config::initialize(
    function ($cfg) {
        $cfg->set_model_directory(BASE_PATH . '/models');
        $cfg->set_connections(
            array(
                'development' => 'mysql://blah:removed@localhost/com_dbname'
            )
        );
    }
);

require_once(BASE_PATH . '/models/model1.php');
require_once(BASE_PATH . '/models/model2.php');
```

**Update**

Adding in actual code to help identify issue:

```
require_once ('../lib/php-activerecord/ActiveRecord.php');

ActiveRecord\Config::initialize(
    function ($cfg) {
        $cfg->set_model_directory('/var/www/uc1/models');
        $cfg->set_connections(
            array(
                'development' => 'mysql://test_usr:test_pwd@localhost/test_db'
            )
        );
    }
);
require_once ('/var/www/uc1/models/ucurls.php'); //Name of model file. Must manually include to get this to work on my nginx server.
$_record = UCUrls::find_by_urlkey('example.com/123');
echo "urlkey=" . $_record->urlkey;
```

Comment: Are the models in a symlinked directory?

Comment: Probably a convention issue, what are the names of your models?

Comment: @sroes - Not a symlinked directory.

Koen - will update with actual code names.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue in windows adding a line in the file **ActiveRecord.php**,

in the function `activerecord_autoload($class_name)`
at the line 39 or 40

```
   $file = "$root/$class_name.php";
    //add this line
   $file = strtolower($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set trace in ActiveRecord.php too look where are ActiveRecord is searching for models.
But I think your issue is in filesystem - Mac OS X by default uses Case Insensitive filesystem, while Ubuntu's Case Sensitive filesystem.

So your model UCUrls should be in file /var/www/uc1/models/UCUrls.php, not in /var/www/uc1/models/ucurls.php